# Git rebase master into newfeature

Tags: git, github

I have the following workflow in GIT.

```
*Master:  feature1 -- feature2 -- hotfix1
                            \
*Feature                     tkt1
```

git rebase master on the feature branch gives me the below result.

### History

```
tkt-1
hotfix-1
feature-2
feature-1
```

I expected the hotfix-1 will be on top of the tkt-1 as master is rebased on the newfeature branch.

Comment: You never told us how the `feature` branch is related to `master`.  This result, from a cursory glance (and guess), does not look wrong to me.  Please update your diagrams.

Comment: @tim: the feature branch is created with (f1&f2)  and not as mentioned below..srry if its not much clear

Comment: Take a look at my answer below.  It will give you an idea of how to use diagrams to clearly show how Git branches are related to each other.  Your current question omits some critical information.

Comment: In the interest of helping you, do you really want the `hotfix-` commit to be on top of `tkt-1`, or were you just curious about why rebasing did what it did?

Comment: Im just curious why rebasing did what it did. I thought rebasing will play the commits of the master at last.

Comment: Actually, it plays the commits from `master` _first_.  This is by design, because Git wanted to create a way for a feature branch to always stay ahead of `master`.

Comment: Thanks much for explaining.

Comment: Read my [blog post](http://codeconnoisseur.com/2014/04/18/several-arguments-for-using-git-rebase/) which does a good job of explaining `git rebase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are simply seeing the result you *should* see from a `git rebase`.  This is what the `master` and `feature` branches looked like before the rebase:

```
master:   f1 -- f2 -- hf1
                  \
feature:            tkt1
```

The most recent common commit between the `master` and `feature` branches is commit `feature2`.  Then you did the following:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

Git played the commits in `master` after the common `f2` commit on top of your `feature` branch, and then recommitted `tkt-1` commit.  This leaves your branches looking like the following:

```
master:   f1 -- f2 -- hf1
                         \
feature:                  tkt1'   (The apostrophe indicates this is a new commit)
```

Or, to use your notation, the rebase left the `feature` branch with the following history:

```
tkt-1
hotfix-1
feature-2
feature-1
```